# 10.2g to 11.2g and Microsoft ODBC for Oracle issues

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, odbc, oracle11g

My team are trying to migrate from ORACLE 10g to 11g. These are our system specs:

Our current production server:

```
ORACLE 10.2g 
ORACLE Application Express(3.0)
Apache
Red Hat 64 bit
```

Our new server (not yet in production):

```
ORACLE 11.2g
ORACLE Application Express (4.1.1)
ORACLE HTTP Server 
Red Hat 64 bit
```

We have managed to setup 11g, install APEX 4.1 and apply the recent patchset. 
The only bit that's delaying us with our migration is that our business users have access to Crystal Reports XI, MS Access/Excel 2003 whcih they use to connect to our database. A typical user has Window XP SP 3 (32bit) operating system. At the moment we are using Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver (version 2.575.1132.00) to connect to our 10g Database and have not had any issues. However when we try connect to 11g we keep getting ORA-03113: end-of-file on communication channel errors. In ORACLE SQL Developer, we're able to connect to our 11g instance using the "basic" connection. I have also used the "TNS" entries and that works well.

I think the business users obtained the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver by installing ORACLE Discover 3.1.3.6 which is used for another Oracle DB. They also have Oracle Client 7.3.3 which I can see Oracle73 (2.00.03.01) mentioned in the ODBM Data Source Admin screen.

We have tried googling for a result and after various tests, we have come to the conclusion that it is an ODBC driver issue. As far as our understand it ORACLE SQL Developer uses a different JAVA based driver to connect so it does not use the Microsoft version.

Can someone confirm that our understanding is correct about there being a compatibility issues with Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver (version 2.575.1132.00) and 11.2g?
If so, what could you recommend a compatible driver to use with Crystal and Access/excel to extract the data?

I think the business users obtained the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver by installing ORACLE Discover 3.1.3.6 which is used for another Oracle DB. They also have Oracle Client 7.3.3 which I can see Oracle73 (2.00.03.01) mentioned in the ODBM Data Source Admin screen.

Answer (score 3):

The Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle is written using an ancient version of the OCI (Oracle Call Interface) API that was deprecated when Oracle 8 was released (which was more than a decade and 11 major releases ago).  Microsoft chose to desupport this driver rather than port it to the new version of the OCI API.  Oracle 7 clients can connect to Oracle 10.2 databases but Oracle does not support connections between Oracle 7 clients and Oracle 11.2 databases.

You'll need to upgrade the version of the Oracle client that is installed on the business user's machines and you'll want to use the latest version of the Oracle ODBC driver that is appropriate for that version of the Oracle client.  Assuming that you install the 11.2 version of the Oracle client (the only reason not to upgrade all the way to the 11.2 client would be if the users still needed to connect to older databases that don't support connections from an 11.2 client), you'd want to use the most recent version of the 11.2.0.x [Oracle ODBC driver](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html).  The Oracle client install should also have the option to install a version of the Oracle ODBC driver-- that should be sufficient as well.

Comment: I think the business users obtained the Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver by installing ORACLE Discover 3.1.3.6 which is used for another Oracle DB. They also have Oracle Client 7.3.3 which I can see Oracle73 (2.00.03.01) mentioned in the ODBM Data Source Admin screen.

Comment: @AlistairLaing - If they've got an old Oracle 7 client, you'll definitely need to upgrade the version of the Oracle client in order for them to be able to connect to an 11.2 database.  I'd suggest installing the 11.2 client on everyone's machines though the 10.2 client would also be sufficient (assuming it's still available).

Comment: So am I right in thinking that it is a compatibility with using Microsoft ODBC for Oracle driver with 11g. Have we simply been lucky that this driver has worked with 10g? So am I right in thinking that ORACLE client just includes the ODBC driver?

Comment: @AlistairLaing - I updated my answer.  The Oracle client includes much more than just the ODBC driver but it does include an ODBC driver.

Comment: Thank you Justin for the excellent explanation, its starting to make some sense. Does it matter which one of those ODAC I download as long as it has the 11g ODBC driver. I’m only really after the driver and do not require sql plus etc. Does this mean everytime we upgrade our database I would need to upgrade the oracle clients as well?

Comment: @AlistairLaing - You can go through a number of database upgrades, in general, before you need to upgrade the client.  Your Oracle 7 clients would have worked fine with Oracle 7.3.4, 8.0.5, 8.0.6, 8.1.5, 8.1.6, 8.1.7, 9.0.1, 9.2.0, 10.1, and 10.2 databases.  But eventually, yes, you'd need to upgrade.  My guess is that you would probably want the XCopy deployment with the Oracle Instant Client though you could also download the (much larger) full Oracle client instead.

Comment: What exactly is Oracle Instant Client? I see "ODAC 11.2 Release 4 (11.2.0.3.0) with Xcopy Deployment" does not include Oracle ODBC Driver.

Comment: @AlistairLaing - Sorry, you're right.  It looks like the ODBC driver isn't available in the XCopy installer, you've got to download the Oracle Universal Installer version (i.e. ODAC112021.zip).  The Instant Client is a slimmed down version of the full client (250 MB rather than 650 MB in this case)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8418/discussion-between-alistair-laing-and-justin-cave)